# Dominoes Tracker using HTML/CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am planning to create a very simple webpage which shows all Dominoes 0-12 and will then allow the user to hover and click each domino to either hide or change its transparency.  The idea is to show what remains based on what has been played.  I am doing this for my wife as a project to help me get a better understanding of html/css and my recently acquired knowledge of jquery and javascript.

At this point my question is simply about the best method to print these dominoes to the page using CSS.  I can create the 0, 1-0, and 1-1 pieces using the code below but I am getting a headache trying to figure out how I can position the dots diagonally for the 0-2. If anyone has the patience to help me with the best method here it would be very much appreciated :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dominoe"> 
        <span class="one">
            <div class="circle"> </div>
        </span>
        <div class="line"> </div>
        <span class="one">
            <div class="circle"> </div> 
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

    * {  
    border: 0.50px dashed blue; /*guide rulers*/
}

.dominoe {
/* Dominoe shape */
    position: relative;
    height:76px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;

/* Rounded Corners 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:2px;
    */
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5px; /* width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal */
    height: 5px; 
    background-color:black;
    position: relative;
    margin:auto;

}

.line {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    height:2%;
    background-color:black;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

.one {
    height:5px;
    width: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
    padding:34%;
}
```

Example of dominoes I am trying to create with CSS:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfwrf.jpg

Comment: Have you considered using image sprite for this?

Comment: No I had not, but now that I have it seems like a good solution for this.  I was trying to accomplish it without any images at all if possible.  It may be more work than it is worth using CSS but I was looking at it as a learning experience rather than a practical application.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use divs instead of spans, they are by default a better-suited element for block display (which in this case, is appropriate)
2. Reformat your dominoe structure logically, i.e. with nested divs.
3. Create 3 classes for each dot position: left, middle, right

Solution is here: http://jsbin.com/ikurip/2/edit

Code for reference:

HTML: as you can see beneath, the dominoe is divided first into two halves, then into 3 parts. After this, positioning the dots horizontally is a piece of cake.

```html
<div class="dominoe"> 
     <div class="half">
       <div class="part">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="part">
         <div class="middle"></div>
       </div>    
       <div class="part">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="line"></div>
     <div class="half"></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS: as you can see, I replaced the circle class by a .part > div selector; so you don't have to create yet another class.

```
* {  
    border: 0.50px dashed blue; /*guide rulers*/
}

.dominoe {
/* Dominoe shape */
    position: relative;
    height:76px;
    width:40px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;

/* Rounded Corners 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:2px;
    */
}

.part > div {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5px; /* width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal */
    height: 5px; 
    background-color:black;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.line {
    width:90%;
    height:2%;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
/* Added CSS */
.dominoe { margin-right: 10px; float: left; }
.half { 
  width: 70%;
  height: 32%;
  padding: 14%;
} 
/* setting padding removes the need to position the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right elements */

.part {
  width: 100%;
  height: 21.333%;
  padding: 8% 0% 8% 0%; 
  /* eliminates need for vertical positioning */
}
.part:first-child {
  padding-top: 0%;
}
.part:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.left {
  float: left;
}
.middle {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Also if you want to have horizontal domino's instead of vertical, you can add this to your CSS:

```css
.horizontal {
     transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

And simply add the 'horizontal' class to a dominoe div.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is something you were looking at over a year ago, but I came across your post today.

A couple of months ago, I was attempting to create a puzzle piece using just HTML and CSS.

I came across this page:

http://sergeylukin.com/css-jigsaw-puzzle-piece/

As I was studying the method used, I got inspired to use the same techniques Mr. Lukin used on his puzzle pieces to create a domino using css and html.  After I figured out one domino, the other 27 were easy.

The result was this:

http://dominocodes.net

I created a class selector for the tile that would give it a 3D feel.

```
.domino {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 6em;
    height: 12em;
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: .8em;
    -moz-border-radius: .8em;
    border-radius: .8em;
    -moz-box-shadow:    .3em .3em 0em .2em #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: .3em .3em 0em .2em #333;
    box-shadow:         .3em .3em 0em .2em #333;
 }
```

Then a grouped class selector to handle the background color for the .domino class and the spans where the pips will be.

```
.domino, .domino span { 
    background-color:#000
  }
```

Another group for putting a line on the tile:

```
.domino .line {
    width: 5.5em;
    height: .2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.7em;
    left: .25em;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Then I came up with a class selector for each possible pip on the domino, which would be seven for the top and seven for the bottom for a total of fourteen class selectors.  I won't list the css for each here. Once you study the two examples here, you can extrapolate and figure out how the rest were done. (Or you can just go to my page and use the Inspect Element tool in your browser to view to view or grab the css.)

I used a the following naming convention for each pip's class selector:

First letter in the name specifies if the pip is for the (T)op or (B)ottom half of the tile.   The second letter specifies if it is on the (L)eft side, (C)enter, or (R)ight side.  The remaining number determines which number combinations the pip would be a part of.
This naming convention would be for a vertical tile.

For example:  The pip that goes in the center of the top of a tile was named TC135, meaning that TC135 is the center pip that participates in a tile with either a One, Three or Five in the top half of the tile.   BR23456 would be the pip on the bottom half that shows a Two, Three, Four, Five or Six.

Each pip has the same width, height, radius and color. The only difference in each of the class selectors is the top and left value.

You will notice that rather than use px for the width, height, top and left, I used em as  Mr. Lukin did in his puzzle piece example.  That allows you to change just one value in the font-size attribute of the domino class selector and the result is that all the dominoes on the page will re-size proportionally. With a little jquery and a spinner element I could let a visitor resize the tiles on the fly with just one line of code. I'm still a jquery newbie, so I haven't tried that yet.

Here's the css for the TC135, BL23456 and BR23456 class selectors:

```
  .domino .TC135 {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.4em;
    left: 2.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    background-color: #fff;
 }

  .domino .BL23456 {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9.6em;
    left: 1.0em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    background-color: #fff;
 }

  .domino .BR23456 {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6.4em;
    left: 4.0em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4em;
    -moz-border-radius: 4em;
    border-radius: 4em;
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

And here is the HTML you would use to build a tile with one pip on the top and two pips on the bottom.

```
<div class="domino">
   <span class="TC135"></span>
   <span class="line"></span>
   <span class="BL23456"></span>
   <span class="BR23456"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the Unicode characters for domino tiles. There is a complete set, facing both vertically and horizontally, starting at U+1F030 and ending at U+1F093.

For example, the 2-3 horizontal domino is at U+1F042, and looks like:

[Here's a chart](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/domino-tiles.html) showing the complete range of domino tiles.

Comment: This is a great idea! I did not realize how deep the Unicode library went.

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit , what an awesome alternative :)

Comment: @user2240945, there's all kinds of fun stuff in there. Dice, playing cards, Egyptian hieroglyphics, smiley faces, you name it.